# Showing functions are characteristic

Tags: probability, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Suppose that $\phi$ is a characteristic function.

How can I prove that $\phi^2$ and $|\phi|^2$ are characteristic functions?

I use the definition of characteristic:

$\phi_x^2(t)=(E(e^{itx}))^2=var(e^{itx})+E(e^{itx})$.

Comment: Do you know the theorem that says something is a characteristic function if and only if......?

Comment: your ask not clear?

Comment: I ask how would you show this? Do you know any theorems that may help?

Comment: I guess @Shashi is referring to Bochner’s theorem, but I’ve never seen that actually being useful (compare the accepted answer to mine in the similar question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2482460/show-that-int-01-phiyt-dy-is-a-characteristic-function-where-phi/2482788#2482788)

Comment: @Dap actually there are properties of the characteristic function that **characterize** the charecteristic function. The theorem goes like $\phi$ is a characteristic function if and only if ......

Comment: @Dap never mind. It is called Bochener's theorem, I see it. I was asking the question to OP to let the OP have a look at the theorems for characteristic function since the question lacked effort...

Answer (score 2):

$(E(e^{itX}))^2$ is $E(e^{it(X+X’})$ where $X’$ is an independent copy of $X.$ So the first one is the characteristic function of $X+X’.$

The second one is similarly the characteristic function of $X-X’.$

Comment: thnx alot , but how you assume that $x^-$ is independent copy of x this allow??

Comment: @nikola: yes, in measure theory terms this is justified by considering the product measure space. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250145/existence-of-iid-random-variables

Comment: just there exist question on my mind whom people answer the problem in this site ? what nautral of this site @Dap